# height : 100% not being inherited

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to align a property in [css](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-error-8ms18?file=/src/styles.css) with :

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

body has `height :100%`, and the described element is the first nested element in body, why it isn't receiving 100% height ?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-error-8ms18?file=/src/Error.js)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly add `height: 100%;` to the id `root` as you are working with react.

```css
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: but can you explain ? cause the body has already 100% height... and inspection shows it is spanned all over the window..